# unable to parse .xt files made from xdebug php extension

Tags: php, xdebug, kcachegrind

for some reason I'm able to create the outputfile inside my /tmp directory but the files aren't readable neither from kcachegrind or wcachegrind (the windows version)

php 5.3.6
xdebug 2.1.1

the file seems correct, here are the first two lines

```
TRACE START [2011-05-06 02:56:09]
0.0323     344532   -> {main}() /localhost/x/test.php:0
```

kcachegrind tells me that the file doesn't have the permission to be read (not true)
wile wincachegrind tells me that its format is inconsistent and it has a parse error at some point.

any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer myself

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger

otherwise files won't be correct for kcachegrind!

Comment: xdebug.profiler_enable = 1 is enough if you want a file for each request.